# What is a new way to disable breakpoint in IDEA 13.1.1?

Tags: intellij-idea, breakpoints, intellij-13

Before, all I had to do it `Alt` + `click` to disable a breakpoint. Docs says it's still possible

[image]

but when I do `Alt` + `click` nothing happens. The only way I can disable it via menu (Run->Toggle Breakpoint Enabled).

Is something changed in newest IDEA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Shift` + `Alt` + `click` works for me for now. It seems like there is an inconsistency between the code and the docs. Maybe this is somehow related to the multiple selection support, the new feature of the IDEA 13.1, because it uses the same shortcut for adding/removing carets.

Comment: I was not even aware of the multiple selection. I will check that as well. Thanks